# ios Mobile project, how to add MXML?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I just downloaded the new Flashbuilder and created a new project for iOS.

I cannot add a new MXML component to it, it says there is no flex project?  Is MXML NOT supported?

Thank you

Comment: Confusion question.  Flash Builder 4.7 supports MXML in Flex Projects and Flex Mobile projects; for all intents and purposes it is no different than Flash Builder 4.6 in that regards. Are you sure you created a Flex Mobile Project? What did you do try to add an MXML Component to 'it' and what is it?  What says there is 'no flex project'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a tool.  I created an "Actionscript Mobile Application".  No wonder.